# How to get each tablerow in regex from a string (C#)?

Tags: c#, regex, string, multiple-matches

Basically, I've got a string like this:

```
<table><tr class="even"><td></td><td></td></tr><tr class="odd"><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
```

I want to get each tablerow using Regex.Matches (c#)

What would my regex pattern be?

I've tried the following but I think it's probably pretty wrong:

```
"<tr"(.*)"</tr>" 
[<][t][r](.*)[<][/][t][r][>]"
```

But even

```
[t][r].*[t][r]
```

Gives 0 matches.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\<tr[\s\S]*?\/tr\>
```

.?* : All Characters, stop at first match.

\s\S : All Characters, even new lines.

I use RAD Software Regular Expression Designer to create and test REGEX expressions. It is a great tool!

Comment: Don't forget that in case of newlines the pattern will fail.

Comment: Yes, that regex must be used in single line mode to catch newlines as well.

Comment: @Casimir: I have added \s\S, that covers all characters, even new line. I have tested and now it works with multiline. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @GerhardPowell Thanks, this works great! I'll take a look at that tool, seems interesting!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var s = @"<table><tr class=""even""><td></td><td></td></tr><tr class=""odd""><td></td><td></td></tr></table>";
Regex.Matches(s, @"(<tr .*?</tr>)", RegexOptions.Singleline)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var str = "<table><tr class=\"even\"><td></td><td></td></tr><tr class=\"odd\"><td></td><td></td></tr></table>";
 string[] trs = Regex.Matches(str, @"<tr[^>]*>(?<content>.*)</tr>", RegexOptions.Multiline)
             .Cast<Match>()
             .Select(t => t.Groups["content"].Value)
             .ToArray();
```

the "trs" array is your result, containing `<td></td><td></td>` two times.

**edit:** This regex is not resilient to missing a `</tr>` (wich would display fine in any browser). This could be solved using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=\<tr.*?\>).*?(?=\</tr\>)
```